# Get rows comparing a column who matches all rows from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

I want to See the rows from Table 1 which column tag matches one or multiple keyword value from Table 2.

Here the Result Should be

id = 1,3,6

in id 1 both 78 and 213 are there but the row will appear 1 time.

I am tried with `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE tag IN (SELECT keyword FROM table2)`. But its returning only those rows Whose Starts matches with Table 2 value like the result came only 3. Because that rows tag starts with 10.

Comment: Hint: Use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

Comment: As per my view in FIND_IN_SET() I can compare 1 value..But not the whole from another table. The purpose is different here. I am not comparing 10 with the column but comparing either 78 or  10 or 213 in tbl1. Thats why I mentioned 2 table. Not value

Comment: I undeleted my answer, but note that you could fairly easily put together my answer using the duplicate link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `FIND_IN_SET` here:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2
              WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t2.keyword, t1.tag) > 0);
```

Note that storing comma separated values in your database is generally not ideal, because it represents unnormalized data.  Instead, get each tag value onto a separate row.

Comment: Thanks for the query. But comparing a huge data will cause a lot of time. Whatever my concern is resolved for now.

Comment: @Hritam You basically can't use an index in my query, because the join comparison is nested inside the `FIND_IN_SET` function.  If you need performance, then get CSV tag value onto a separate record, and then add an appropriate index.